# Popup Java Script

Tags: javascript, mvc, razor

Hola necesito su ayuda nuevamente, necesito hacer un VerDetalles del seguimiento, ya tengo hecho el select y me devuelve los campos requeridos.
En la controller tengo la función DetallesTracking
En la parte que necesito vuestra ayuda es en el javascript que no tengo idea de cómo hacer la función,  ya la he empezado pero no sé por dónde tirar.
Soy nuevo en esto de MVC y Razor y aun no le acabo de coger el truquillo.

El enlace html -> js->controller->js->html

El resultado final debe ser mostrado como una tabla en un popup

Si necesitan los archivos los tengo a vuestra disposición.
Gracias de antemano.

Aquí os dejo la función de la controller

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult DetallesTracking(string numeroguia)
    {
        var rootObject = new JObject()
        {
            new JProperty("tracking", JObject.Parse("{}"))
        };

        try
        {
            System.Text.StringBuilder stbSQL = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

            stbSQL.AppendLine("SELECT convert(varchar(100),fhit,106) as Fecha, ");
            stbSQL.AppendLine("hhit as Hora, ");
            stbSQL.AppendLine("dtrk as Tracking, ");
            stbSQL.AppendLine("hit.dhit as Descripcion ");
            stbSQL.AppendLine("FROM aebtrk trk ");
            stbSQL.AppendLine("INNER JOIN aebhit hit on trk.ihit = hit.ihit ");
            stbSQL.AppendLine("INNER JOIN tdahaw tda on trk.creg = tda.itdahaw ");
            stbSQL.AppendLine("INNER JOIN tdaprehaw prehaw on tda.itdahaw = prehaw.itdahaw");
            stbSQL.AppendFormat("WHERE tda.ctdahaw like '{0}'", numeroguia).AppendLine();
            stbSQL.AppendLine("ORDER BY Fecha ASC ");


            CopaCursoEntities dbbf = new CopaCursoEntities();
            DetallesTracking detallesTracking = dbbf.Database.SqlQuery<DetallesTracking>(stbSQL.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();

            if (detallesTracking != null)
            {
                rootObject["tracking"] = JToken.FromObject(detallesTracking);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var tokenError = JToken.FromObject(e);
            rootObject["error"] = JToken.FromObject(e);
        }

        return new ContentResult
        {
            Content = rootObject.ToString(),
            ContentType = "application/json"
        };

    }
```

aquí la función de *JS*:

```
VerDetalles = function () {

    var url = $("#UrlDetallesTracking").val();
    var numeroguia = $("#txtTracking").val();

    if (numeroguia == '') {
        return;
    }

    showLoader(Resources.consultando_tracking);
    var data = { numeroguia: numeroguia }
    $.get(url, data, function (result) {
        if (underscore.has(result, "error")) {
            mostrarMensajeKo(Resources.intente_mas_tarde, 3000);
        }
        else {




        }
    }

    );

}
```

y aquí la sección de *HTML* donde esta el botón que hace la llamada a la función *js*.

```
 <div class="col-3"><input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm w-100" id="detallestracking" value="Ver detalles" onclick="VerDetalles();"/></div>
```

Comment: Por favor, lee cómo prepara un [mcve], hazlo e incluye el código en tu pregunta. Un saludo.

Comment: puedo añadir las funciones o adjuntar directamente los archivos en los que estoy programando

Comment: Si ya tienen un [mcve] adelante, incluye el código. Si aún no lo tienen, la idea es que tu lo reduzcas al mínimo de código necesario para mostrar el problema que tienes. ¿leíste el artículo enlazado?

Comment: si lo he leido, y detallo los tres elementos involucrados, solo que la funcion JS no esta completa porque no tengo ni idea de como hacer para que muestre un popup con los datos que devuelve la controller